# Is $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ always injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Is $T: V \rightarrow V$ always injective?

My thoughts would be that it is since $V$ is isomorphic to $V$.

There is a bijection. But I feel like I have seen examples where this is not true.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What about $T = 0$?

Comment: What about a projection from the plane to a line?

Comment: It sounds like you might need to review the definition of [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and how it relates to the notation "$f:A\to B$". See also [the difference between codomain and range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317941/what-is-the-difference-between-codomain-and-range).

Comment: Your conjecture is equivalent to every square matrix being invertible, which is false.  Let $A$ be any $n \times n$ matrix with $0$ determinant.  Define $T(x)=Ax$ for $x \in V$ with a chosen basis, $n=\dim(V)$.

Comment: Wait a minute....You think that it is true and then you say that you have "seen examples where this is not true". Then why would you think this is true?. If someone told you that all movies are boring and you already have seen some which are not then why would you agree to that person saying that all movies are boring? . That being said....Randall's comment should be sufficient to satisfy your query

Comment: It is true that $V$ is isomorphic to $V$, which is to say there is at least one invertible linear map from $V$ to $V$ (canonical example: the identity map). It does not mean that *every* linear map $T : V \to V$ is invertible!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, $T$ does not need to be injective. However, assuming $\operatorname{dim}V < \infty$, it follows from the [nullity rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem#Stating_the_theorem) that $T: V \to V$ is injective iff $T$ is surjective.

Comment: How does this help the question of the op?

Comment: It was asked if every linear map from $V$ to $V$ is injective. Since the op thought it was the case (from the isomorphism), it might be pertinent to state when such a map is injective. I am not above deleting the answer if it is not pertinent.