# Is the range of a matrix transformation a subspace of the column or null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was not sure how to phrase the question, but I am checking my understanding of *Interactive Linear Algebra's* section on [one-to-one matrix transformations](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/one-to-one-onto.html#matrix-trans-one-to-one). My question is about the validity of the last statement of the theorem. Why does not it not have dimension **m**?

**Theorem (One-to-one matrix transformations).** Let A be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $T(x) = Ax$ be the associated matrix transformation. The following statements are equivalent:

1. *T is one-to-one.*
2. *For every $b$ in $R^m$, the equation $T(x)=b$ has at most one solution.*
3. *For every $b$ in $R^m$ , the equation $Ax = b$ has a unique solution or is inconsistent.*
4. *$Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution*
5. *The columns of $A$ are linearly independent.*
6. *$A$ has a pivot in every column.*
7. *The range of $T$ has dimension $n$.*

Based on their previous [definition](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/matrix-transformations.html#definition-26) of the domain, codomain, image, and range:

**Defintition.** A transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$ is a rule $T$ that assigns to each vector $x$ in $R^n$ a vector $T(x)$ in $R^m$.

- $R^n$ is called the ***domain*** of $T$.
- $R^m$ is called the ***codomain*** of $T$.
- For $x$ in $R^n$, the vector $T(x)$ in $R^m$ is the ***image*** of $x$ under $T$
- The set of all images {$T(x) \ | \ x \ \text{in} \ R^n$} is the range of $T$

I think I might just be confusing their use of image vs range. I checked this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3141287/1230700) here too and it seems like there is no standard. But I would like to understand what this specific text is trying to convey. Are the number of dimensions related to the x (of $R^n$). How does that relate to the rank which is defined in other places as the dimensions of the range?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the answer. We are referring to an injective (one-to-one) matrix transformation. Another way of thinking of injections is that every output comes from a unique input, so the range is limited to the inputs, the domain (or $R^n$). Later on in the text, when we are referring to surjective (onto) matrix transformations, the range of $T$ has dimension $m$, which follows from the definition that every output has some input (which may or not be unique). This is the original line of reasoning I was thinking. A bijective function is both injective and surjective, see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2199729/1230700) for further reading if you stumble on this question while going through the text.

Comment: “Every input has a unique output.” That’s the definition of s function. You mean that each output comes from a unique input. Quite different!

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh right. I'll edit and switch it around. Did everything else look correct?

Comment: There are small errors — like saying the range is $m$. A set is not a number.

Comment: @TedShifrin I changed that to say that it has dimension m (to match the text). I am trying to make sure I don't have any gaps in my understanding, so if you have any more comments, I'd love to hear them.